# Is it possible to construct a chrono_tz variant from a String or &str?

Tags: rust, timezone

I am trying to figure out how I can use the enum variants which are part of [Chrono Tz](https://docs.rs/chrono-tz/0.8.3/chrono_tz/index.html).

For example, there is a variant called `Europe__London`.

https://docs.rs/chrono-tz/latest/chrono_tz/enum.Tz.html#variant.Europe__London

I don't understand how to use it, and I haven't been able to find any documentation or other resources to help. I have attempted to inspect the source code, but the browser crashed while trying to open it. (Out of memory.)

I also tried looking at the source on [Github](https://github.com/chronotope/chrono-tz), but it appears, unless I misunderstand, that the source code is actually being auto generated by querying an [IANA database via a web interface](https://www.iana.org/time-zones).

Can a `chrono::Tz` object be created from a `String` or `&str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be possible using the following code.

```
// timezone = &str ...

let chrono_timezone = Tz::from_str(timezone)
    .expect("failed to convert string to chrono tz");
```

---

This is how I reverse-engineered what the valid timezone strings were:

```
// Cargo.toml: 
// chrono-tz = "0.8.3"
use chrono::Tz;

fn main() {
    
    let chrono_timezone = Tz::Europe__London;

    println!("{:?}", chrono_timezone);

    let timezone_str = "Europe/London";
    
    let chrono_timezone = Tz::from_str(timezone_str)
        .expect("failed to convert string to chrono tz");

    println!("{:?}", chrono_timezone);
}
```

I knew to use `Europe__London` as it features in this [list](https://docs.rs/chrono-tz/latest/chrono_tz/enum.Tz.html#variant.Europe__London).

That appears to be equivalent to this:

```
let chrono_timezone = chrono_tz::Europe::London;
```

See [this link](https://docs.rs/chrono-tz/0.8.3/chrono_tz/Europe/constant.London.html).